# Delete all files that are set to hidden or read only or system

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax, delete-file

I want to remove all the `jpg`, `ini` and more types in current folder and all the sub folders, then delete all the empty folders (recursively). Some of those files are either read only or hidden or even set to system so just the `del /s *.jpg` doesn't remove them. The problem is it looks like the syntax is using logic `and` when I do: `del /a:h /a:r /s *.jpg` so only read only and hidden files are removed but not only hidden files. Is there a way to make it use logic `or` instead?

I couldn't find examples to make it work without copy pasting the same lines with small changes.

About `rmdir`, do I have to do `cd` to the current folder? because it says there's a syntax error in the code below:

```
del /s *.jpg
del /a:h /a:r /s *.jpg
rmdir /s /q
pause
```

EDIT3: I think that now it deletes everything with: `del /s /f /a:h /a:a *.jpg`

I found this for removing empty folders but it doesn't work if the folder is set to read only:

https://superuser.com/a/39679/451485

Comment: You need to specify the directory you want to remove with `rmdir`. You can't remove the current directory. You'll need to change to some other directory, that's not a child of the directory, and then remove it using the name of the directory. All you need is `rmdir /s /q c:\foo`. It will remove everything in the directory `c:\foo` and all subdirectories, including read-only, hidden or system files.

Comment: @RossRidge I want to remove just empty folders from the current and all sub folders. Doesn't `rmdir` works the same as in bash and remove only empty folders?

Comment: `rmdir /s /q` is like `rm -rf`. It removes everything.

Comment: So is there another way to delete all the empty folders and subfolders? @RossRidge

Comment: If the folder you want to empty out is the current directory, this should work: `rd /s /q .` or you can create an empty folder and then say `robocopy /e /purge emptyfolder foldertoempty`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but I believe the following will work:

```
@echo off

:: Remove readonly / hidden / system attributes from all files of interest
attrib -r -h -s *.jpg /s
attrib -r -h -s *.ini /s
rem etc...

:: Delete the files of interest
del /s *.jpg *.ini

:: for each folder, sorted descending by full path (children come before parent)
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad /s *^|sort /r') do (
  REM check if folder is empty
  dir /b /a "%%F" | findstr "^" >nul || (
    REM remove directory with /S /Q works, even if folder is read only
    rd /s /q "%%F"
  )
)
```

Comment: I haven't got time to test it, but is it possible to remove all the attributes from all the folders too?

Comment: @ kuhaku - `attrib -r -h -s * /d /s` would remove attributes from all files and folders. But I assumed you would not want to alter files or folders that were not being deleted. BTW, I don't understand the statement "I don't have time to test". If not , then you don't have time to program.

Comment: I have no use for those for attributes. With removing all the attributes it now clears a lot more files but it looks like it doesn't clear the read only from the folders. Well the `for` loop in your answer does clear them all up.

I was preoccupied with other stuff that's why I didn't have time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hmm looks like the for loop misses some folders here and there, they're read only but I see that it does remove most of the other folders that are read only too.